# Sharing Sessions on different Asp.Net pages of different Applications in same domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session-state, session-management

Basically we are working on various web applications which are updated according to the time needs and Now the situation arises are as follows:-
 We have one Product based website which consists of several webpages which are belongs to different Web applications. In each application there is session management done. but stored in sql server and then transferred to various pages. Now it slows the application at some point of time because every time on page loads it gets or sets the session variable from sql server. So to reduce the sql server hit, I think that the shared session between these application will reduce the server hits and It is helpful in speeding up the website. So Is any method available for this or we can do any thing else for this. So help me...

Comment: Are those different applications currently sharing same Session State from SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, the whole application sharing same session state and stored in sql server, At the time of Login main Application stores all the session variable  into SQL Server then when another application comes into contact then it checks for the available session if not then retrives from SQL Server (read and then write), which slows down the system at some instant, I want to remove this read-write overhead...